# How to check if exactly one value in an iterable resolves to True?

Tags: python, list, expression

Is there an elegant, readable way to check if all the elements in an iterable `it` resolve to `True` (you may assume all values are boolean though that's not relevant to my question)? I came up with:

`any(it) and not reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, it)`

but I think the reduce makes it somewhat confusing to understand plus I don't think it works:

```
In [1]: a=[True, True, False]

In [7]: any(a) and not reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, a)
Out[7]: True
```

Are there more readable ways?

**Update**: I realized the error in my expression above. reduce() needs to *stop* when it sees a True and not continue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your title disagrees with the body of your question, but I'll answer the title.

You can `sum` boolean values.  Check if it's equal to 1 (or whatever value you'd like):

```
>>> a = [True, True, False]
>>> sum(a)
2
>>> b = ['hey', '', 'a string']
>>> sum(map(bool,b))
2
```

Comment: I like this answer the best.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using `count`:

```
>>> a=[True, True, False]
>>> if a.count(True) == 1:
...     print 'Hello'
... else:
...     print 'Sorry'
Sorry
```

### Examples

```
>>> [True, False].count(True) == 1
True

>>> [True, True, False].count(True) == 1
False

>>> [True, True, False].count(False) == 1
True
```

Comment: Interesting. Would this work if the elements are not all explicitly Boolean?

Comment: @scorpiodawg, What else will they be?

Comment: What about lambdas that return boolean values?

Comment: @scorpiodawg, Yes. Lambda will return a list of booleans that you can then check.

Answer (score 0):

So, the general format for this is something like this:

```
test = [True, True, False]
if len([x for x in test if x]) == 1:
    # Do something
```

Of course, the above is just testing if `x` is boolean `True`, but you could put any kind of comparison there.

You might say, but isn't that inefficient? Not really, if you really want exactly N items - you'd have to check them all anyways to see if there is another `True` lurking in there.

For the case where it's 'N or more' items, you can kind of (ab)use generators to do this:

```
from itertools import islice
result = True
g = (x for x in test if x)
if len(list(islice(g, 2))) == 2: 
    # do something
```

This is a bit of a shortcut, since it will stop as soon as it sees the number of items and not walk farther through the generator. If you wanted to use this form for an exact count, it has a small advantage over the list form:

```
if len(list(islice(g, 2))) == 2 and not any(g):
    # do something
```

Why does this have a small advantage? In the passing case, we still have to look through every other item to make sure there are exactly 2 `Trues` in the list. But in the failing case, as soon as we see another `True`, the `any` will shortcut and you won't walk through the rest of the list.